# What is the best practice to reject request with large delay?

Tags: node.js, http, synchronization, httprequest

I'm trying to build really simple, but useful application. When pressing button on client device (e.g android application), a POST request are sent to the "gateway" server which then notify listeners about event that was raised on client. So, listeners (there could be many of them) should perform some action depending on button that was pressed on client.

The problem is - due to many reason there are chances that delay between button press and listeners starts to perform some actions is big. In my opinion 2 seconds is maximum delay allowed. How could I achieve that? Simple timestamps aren't solution because I have 3 machines in chain which could be not synchronized in time.

Particularly in my example I use android application as client which raises events, remote nodejs application as gateway which is listening to the clients and local nodejs application which is listening to the gateway server.

Comment: You should probably just cancel requests on the client side.

Comment: @vkurchatkin it's not just one request, but chain. First request could be OK, but there could be some delay in the next element of chain.